Manim animations in Jupyter notebooks (VSC) saved with a wrong filename
I am trying to use Manim Community Edition in a jupyter notebook run inside of Visual Studio Code on MacOS Sonoma 14.5.
The first cell ever run prepared the animation in a class named GridWithParallelepipeds.mp4. I copied the text in another cell and turned it into:
from manim import *
config.media_width = "100%"

class A(ThreeDScene):
    def construct(self):
        self.set_camera_orientation(phi=75 * DEGREES, theta=-45 * DEGREES)
        
        square = Square(side_length=1, fill_color=GREEN, fill_opacity=1)
        square.move_to([100, 100, 0])
        self.add(square)
        self.wait()

        self.move_camera(phi=75 * DEGREES, theta=-45 * DEGREES, frame_center=[100, 100, 0])        
        self.wait()

scene = A()
scene.render()

When I run this cell I get:
INFO     Animation 0 : Partial movie file written in scene_file_writer.py:527
                             '/Users/user/tests/manim-gnn/media/videos/1080p60/partial                         
                             _movie_files/A/3737776177_3467822883_1843901289.mp4'                             

The first message says that it is saving partial movie files in the path /Users/.../A. Notice the A in the path. It correctly corresponds to the class name. Other messages similar to the previous one follow, then the output ends with:
INFO     Combining to Movie file.
INFO
         File ready at                                                                         
         '/Users/user/tests/manim-gnn/media/videos/1080p60/GridWithParallelepipeds.mp4'  

As you can see it wrote the complete movie in a file named GridWithParallelepipeds.mp4, which is the name of the class producing a different animation.
In order to have the movie saved with filename A.mp4 I need to restart the kernel.
If I run the single "animations" as Python scripts, I have no problems with the output filename.
Questions:
is it possible to use manim-ce inside of notebooks in VSC? Is there anyone who knows how to have the animations saved with the correct filenames?
Versions:
MacOS 14.5
Python 3.9.18
VSC 1.89.1
VSC python extensions: v2024.8.1
VSC Jupyter: v2024.4.0
Manime CE: 0.18.1

